# How I Post This array in AJAX using AppendGrid plug in

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I use [AppendGrid](http://appendgrid.apphb.com/Demo/HeaderDetail) as my plugin for table insert form containing header and detail.

Here is my code :

```
$('#tblAppendGrid').appendGrid({
        initRows: 1,
        columns: [
                { name: 'CodeNo', display: 'Code No', type: 'text', ctrlCss: { 'text-align': 'center' },ctrlAttr: { maxlength: '10' }},
                { name: 'CartonNo', display: 'Carton No', type: 'text', ctrlCss: {'text-align': 'center'},ctrlAttr: { maxlength: '10' }},
                { name: 'JawNo', display: 'Jaw No', type: 'text',ctrlCss: { 'text-align': 'center' },ctrlAttr: { maxlength: '10' }},
                { name: 'Time', display: 'Time', type: 'text', ctrlAttr: { maxlength: '10' }, 
                ctrlCss: {'text-align': 'center' }, value: '<?php echo"$jam_ini";?>'},
                { name: 'wos', display: 'Weight Of Sample(67-72 g)', 
                    type: 'text', ctrlAttr: { maxlength: 10 }, ctrlCss: { 'text-align': 'center' }},
                { name: 'odour', display: 'Odour/flavour&Taste (Normal)*', 
                    type: 'select', ctrlOptions: {V: 'V',X: 'X'},ctrlCss: {'align': 'center' }},
                { name: 'ph', display: 'pH(6,0-6,4)', type: 'text', ctrlAttr: { maxlength: '10' }, ctrlCss: {'text-align': 'center' }},
                { name: 'et', display: 'Electrolit Test (Negative)', type: 'select', ctrlOptions: {N: 'N',P: 'P'}
                    ,ctrlCss: {'align': 'center' }},
                { name: 'it', display: 'Ink. Test(Negative)**', type: 'select', ctrlOptions: {N: 'N',P: 'P','':''},
                    ctrlCss: {'align': 'center' }},
                { name: 'remark', display: 'Remark', type: 'text', ctrlAttr: { maxlength: '10' }, ctrlCss: {'text-align': 'center' }}

            ]
    });
    // Dummy: Handle save button clicked
    $('#tombolsave').button().click(function () {
    $("#status").html("Saving...");
    $("#loading").show();
    var HeaderID = $("#HeaderID").val();
    var UserName = $("#UserName").val();
    var date = $("#date").val();
    var bop = $("#bop").val();
    var pdate = $("#pdate").val();
    var exdate = $("#exdate").val();    
    var line = $("#line").val();
    var toi = $("#toi").val();
    var data = $('#tblAppendGrid').appendGrid('getAllValue');
    var count =  $('#tblAppendGrid').appendGrid('getRowCount');

    for (var i=0;i<=count;i++){
    var CodeNo = data[i].CodeNo;
    var CartonNo = data[i].CartonNo;
    var JawNo = data[i].JawNo;
    var Time = data[i].Time;
    var wos = data[i].wos;
    var odour = data[i].odour;
    var ph = data[i].ph;
    var et = data[i].et;
    var it = data[i].it;
    var remark = data[i].remark;
    alert(it);

    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: "aksi.php",
            data: "op=save&HeaderID="+HeaderID+"&UserName="+UserName+"&date="+date+"&bop="+bop+
            "&pdate"+pdate+"&exdate="+exdate+
            "&line="+line+"&toi"+toi+"&i="+i+
            "&CodeNo[]="+CodeNo+"&CartonNo[]"+CartonNo+"&JawNo[]="+JawNo+
            "&Time[]="+Time+"&wos[]"+wos+"&odour[]="+odour+"&ph[]="+ph+"&et[]"+et+"&it[]="+it+
            "&remark[]="+remark,
            cache: false,
            success: function(msg){
            if(msg=="sukses"){
            $("#status").html("Berhasil...");
            $("#loading").hide();
            document.location.reload();
            }else{
            $("#status").html("ERROR..");
            }
            }
        });
        }
    });
});
```

My problem in AJAX POST, how I can post each detail value and how I use it in **aksi.php**.
Hope this can make sense.

Answer (score 0):

in your script nothing wrong you just forget to add this "=" in a part like `"&CartonNo[]"+CartonNo` to `"&CartonNo[]="+CartonNo`

on aksi.php just make an array like

```
//script connect to database    
for($i = 0; $i< $max; $i++){
    //detail
    $CartonNo =     $_POST[CartonNo][$i];
    ....
    //sql action
    }
```